# Replace <br /> using sed does not work

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I want to remove `<br />` from a file using `sed -i ...`.

The `/` gives me trouble.

This works:

```
sed -i e 's/<br/''/g' File.txt
```

But this didn't work:

```
sed -i e 's/'<br />'/''/g' File.txt
```

Comment: Please ask you question in full english.

Answer (score 0):

Use any other char after the `s`

```
sed -i 's_/_+_'
```

Should work

the `s` subcommand from sed means **substitution**, and uses the next char as a delimiter, it could be *almost* anything. but it is a good pratice to not use any char that is related to your target text (HTML in this case), like `<>/#.`

Also it is advisable to avoid shell relevant ones `$!()`

Comment: Thank You! Rafareino, it works great.